# VB.NET MDI Children Focus only on Title Bar Click

Tags: vb.net, focus, titlebar, mdichild

One would imagine that clicking anywhere within the MDI Child form (or on any control) will focus that form. But in my application I can only focus a MDI child by clicking on its titlebar, which is an abnormal behavior on the part of the user. My forms are filled with either controls or panels so I don't have the luxury of just "clicking on the form." But clicking anywhere within it should focus it.

I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem although it seems others are having it as well.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. If you are setting the child form `mdiParent` property after you are calling `Form.Show` then it messes up the focus of all the child forms.

When I set `mdiParent` property of the form first and then call `.Show()`, everything works perfectly as expected.

Comment: In my case I was forced to do so because I created mdi children programmatically... I found no other way around it.